# Cart Abandonment Rate report

Tags: google-analytics

I've read web analytics 2.0 from Avinash Kaushik and wondered how to create report on Cart Abandonment rate in Google Analytics. I want to create what Avinash describes as:

> Cart Abandonment Rate (in percent terms) = [1 – (the total number of people who start checkout divided by the total number of add to cart clicks)].<sup>1</sup>

I thought of creating goal, but really? Goal is simple and this is not simple. Please someone point me in the right direction about how to do this.

I can find the total number of add to cart clicks from All pages standard report. I can also find the total number of people who start the checkout process from All pages standard report, but I am unsure how to retrieve these 2 numbers and create a rate in one report.

<sup>1</sup><sub>http://www.kaushik.net/avinash/excellent-analytics-tip-7-the-adorable-site-abandonment-rate-metric/</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Goals is the way to go. [Here is an article that walks you through the process of setting up a funnel for this](http://www.barilliance.com/blog/2012/07/how-to-measure-shopping-cart-abandonment-rate-in-google-analytics/).

> 1. Click on admin, select your profile and the click on the Goals tab
> 2. Enter a descriptive name for the Goal, we’ll call ours “Cart to Purchase”
> 3. In Goal type select URL Destination and enter the URL of your order confirmation page. This page is typically accessed only when an order is completed
> 4. Click the Use funnel checkbox to add the necessary steps to complete an order. In the screenshot below you can see that I added the cart page as step one and the checkout page as step two.
> 5. Save your Goal.

Comment: Hi Stephen, I've read that one. However it is unclear to me how funnel exactly works. What if user visits some different page from /cart to /cashout and then comesback to cashout. Is such visit in exit rate or not ?